# What kind of USB connector is this?

Tags: usb

What kind of funny connector is this?  The big part is a USB-A connector, and plugs into a standard USB-A female connector (although it's a bit tight).  But what is the other thing?  It appears to have 5 pins.  It's about the size and shape of a USB micro-B male connector, but I don't see any way for it to plug into a female connector--possibly I could pry the USB-A part off, but I don't see how without damaging it.

[image: top view] [image: side view][image: another view]